# How do I disable bpython colored output?

Tags: shell, archlinux, bpython

bpython by default has a really nice blue theme, but it doesn't go well with light backgrounds. How can I disable its colour output and have it give just plain black (on [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [theme](https://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/en/latest/themes.html#themes) that only uses black as an output color. That might look like:

```
[syntax]
keyword = k
name = k
comment = k
string = k
error = k
number = K
operator = K
punctuation = k
token = K
paren = K

[interface]
background = d
output = k
main = k
prompt = k
prompt_more = k
right_arrow_suggestion = K
```

This is based on the [default theme](https://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/en/latest/themes.html#default-theme), replacing all the colors with `k` (for normal black) or `K` (for bold black).

Save this in `~/.config/bpython/light.theme` and then set `color_scheme = light` in `~/.config/bpython/config`.

Comment: @xpusostomos this is an answer...it's not tagged at all! Did you mean to leave that comment on the question?